# I am new to ARM assembly language and can you help explain why I am not getting the correct Celsius Average in the correct register?

Tags: assembly, arm

The problem statement asks to take 16 temperature values in Celsius ranging from 0-45 and average them, storing them both in an array. (We are to make up the values to be in the array)

When I run my program I am not getting the correct value in register R2for the Average?

This is using ARM assembly language with a BeagleBone Black and a TI XDS 100V2 JTAG Emulater. I am using CCS to run all of this program.

```
.text
.global _start
_start:

.EQU        NUM,8

            LDR R1,=CELSIUS_TEMPS        @ load pointer to array
            LDR R2,=CELSIUS_AVG          @ load pointer to Celsius_Av array
            MOV R3,#NUM                  @ initialize counter 
    NEXT:   LDRB R6,[R1],#1              @ get first cels_temp byte, increment pointer
            LDRB R7,[R1],#1              @ get second cels_temp byte, increment pointer
            ADDS R4,R7,R6                @ add sum in R6
            ADDS R8,R8,R4                @ add sum in R4
            SUBS R3,R3,#1                @ decrement element counter
            BNE NEXT                     @ repeat loop
            MOVS R8,R8,LSR #4            @ divide by 16 LSB to carry
            ADC R8,R8,#0                 @ add contents of carry flag to sum in R6 to round result up if carry=1
            STRB R8,[R2]                 @ copy resulted byte to Celsius_Av array

.DATA
CELSIUS_TEMPS:  .byte  0x00,0x03,0x06,0x9,0x0C,0x0F,0x12,0x15,0x18,0x1B,0x1E,0x21,0x24,0x27,0x2A,0x2D
CELSIUS_AVG:    .byte 0x00

.end
```

Like I said in the question I am new to this and I am getting a big number for the average (0x10200000), for the temperatures I have chosen I should be getting 22 or 23 for the average. (0x16 or 0x17 for hex)

Comment: What *are* you getting?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic explains that you need to show actual output as well as desired output.  (Ideally also go through your code with a debugger to watch register values change.)

Comment: @fuz: Isn't `[reg], #imm` a post-increment?  I think this is just unrolling by 2 and that part looks ok.  (I guess you agree since you already deleted your earlier comment)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, I had a brainfart about the syntax for a moment.

Comment: I am getting 0x10200000 after it runs through.

Comment: [edit] your question instead of leaving info buried in comments.

Comment: A `.byte` can't hold a number that large, only 0..255; How are you examining the contents of the byte at `CELSIUS_AVG:`?

Comment: *I am not getting the correct value in register R2*  R2 holds a pointer, not the value itself.  You only set R2 with `LDR R2,=CELSIUS_AVG`.  Is `0x10200000` the address of that label?

Comment: BTW, since you're unrolling you might consider doing one word load and then masking it with `0x00FF00FF`, basically doing a SWAR (SIMD within a register) horizontal add.  Your sum only needs to be 16 bits wide to handle the sum of any reasonable number of bytes.

Comment: I think you forgot to zero `R8` before the loop.  IDK why you'd end up with such a nice round number at the end, though, if `0x10200000` is really the value in R8.  This still isn't a [mcve] because you don't show where / how you found that big value.